# Use default application as file thumbnail in Mint's file browser

Tags: linux-mint, nemo, thumbnails

In Mint's default file browser (which is Nemo, as far as I know), I'd like to set the icon of the default application for a certain file type as the thumbnail for all files of this file type. For example I'd like all `.odt` files to have the icon of the LibreOffice Writer as their thumbnail, and all `.pdf` files to have the icon of the respective PDF editor. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't  can give you a complete answer. As far i recognice the Pictures are in /path/to/iconset/icon-size/mimetypes/*  and /path/to/iconset/scalable/mimetypes/*

Comment: But that would mean I had to do it manually for each file type... But it would be something so thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use neither Mint nor Nemo but thumbnailer are controlled by files placed in this folder `/usr/share/thumbnailers/`

e.g. if you don't want ".odt" thumbnails, exclude that extension from the right thumbnailer, in my case `gsf-office.thumbnailer`

Comment: I don't have an office thumbnailer nor one for the pdfs...

Comment: @Raven, what is the output of `ls /usr/share/thumbnailers/`?

Comment: The output is `gnome-font-viewer.thumbnailer  xplayer.thumbnailer  xreader.thumbnailer
`

Comment: @Raven, try to investigate on them, or better on the `xreader` one... post the output of `cat /usr/share/thumbnailers/xreader.thumbnailer`

Comment: `[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=xreader-thumbnailer
Exec=xreader-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
MimeType=application/pdf;application/x-bzpdf;application/x-gzpdf;application/x-xzpdf;application/postscript;application/x-bzpostscript;application/x-gzpostscript;image/x-eps;image/x-bzeps;image/x-gzeps;application/x-dvi;application/x-bzdvi;application/x-gzdvi;image/vnd.djvu;image/tiff;application/x-cbr;application/x-cbz;application/x-cb7;application/x-cbt;image/*;application/oxps;application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument;application/epub+zip;`

Comment: @Raven, as you can see, `xreader-thumbnailer` handles PDFs, hence if you want to disable thumbnailing for PDFs, this should be the right way

Comment: Okay I'll try to delete it and then see whether it worked... Thank you!

Comment: Okay it removed the thumbnails so that part is working... But it's still using some arbitrary icon for the files (it's actually the same one for `.odt` and `.pdf` (and maybe some more)

Answer (score 3):

Install dconf-tools, Navigate to org > gnome > desktop > thumbnailer, Paste the MIME type in the value field of disable key (as described for PDF files [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136024/how-to-stop-nautilus-from-creating-thumbnails-of-specific-file-types)).

This will not delete existing thumbnails for files, but once a file is updated or for new files - no thumbnails will be produced.

For pdf: 'application/pdf'

For odt: 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text' (A full list of LibreOffice mime types can be found [here](https://github.com/qt-haiku/LibreOffice/blob/master/sysui/desktop/solaris/mime.types)).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that you are seeing "previews" instead of icons.

Nemo has three views: icon view, list view, and compact view.

By default, in the icon and list views, for files on your local disk, Nemo will show you previews of the document instead of an icon for it's associated application.  For files on a remote file system, and in compact view, you'll see the application icon.

Use Edit->Preferences and then the Preview tab to change that config.

Comment: Well as far as I have seen it I can only disable the preview completely for all file types but it would still be nice if I had a preview of let's say images and videos...